# Zoom Slider DJI widget

Tags: java, android, dji-sdk

I need to zoom in my app and it appears that in the **DJIPilot** app there is something that looks like a widget for a zoom, but I can't find it in the documentation, does anyone know what widget is this? I put a picture of this widget.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGbdd.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It's a widget in a closed, heavily encrypted app. You can't access it.

I don't know why you think it should be available in the SDK? Dji App and SDK are two different things. DJI apps don't even use the sdk.

You have to do it yourself, or find some similar somewhere else.

There are some simple widgets in UXSDK, you can look there, but I doubt you find anything good enough.